# программа modprobe не видит драйвер

Tags: linux, ubuntu

lsmod утилиты почему то в убунту нету. `apt-get install lsmod` также не сработал.

воспользовался программой  modprobe она мне выдает

```
comp@comp0:/lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic$ sudo modprobe ofd.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module ofd.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic
```

сам файл лежит в директории `/lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/` ofd.ko

```
comp@comp0:/lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic$ ls
build   modules.alias      modules.builtin.bin  modules.devname  modules.symbols      vdso
initrd  modules.alias.bin  modules.dep          modules.order    modules.symbols.bin
kernel  modules.builtin    modules.dep.bin      modules.softdep  ofd.ko
```

В общем залить драйвер не представляется возможным. Как это исправить ??

Comment: apt-get install kmod

Comment: `$ sudo modprobe ofd`

Comment: Утилиты пакета `kmod` установлены в каталог */sbin*, куда по умолчанию только суперпользователь доступ (можно добавить к себе в `PATH`, но это не позволит их запускать от простого пользователя всё равно). А сам модуль, конечно же, должен находится чуть глубже, хотя бы на уровне *kernel*. И вообще, для сторонних модулей есть каталог *extras*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем kmod установил и не парился.

```
sudo apt-get install kmod
```

После вызвал команды

```
 sudo su 
 insmod ofd.ko
 lsmod | head -10
```